# How to transform the string "AABSSSD" into "2AB3SD"?

Tags: java, string

I want to transform the string `AABSSSD` into `2AB3SD` (someone called it encryption).
This is how I tried to resolve it:

```
public class TransformString {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "AABSSSD";
        StringBuilder newStr = new StringBuilder("");
        char temp = str.charAt(0);
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            if (temp == str.charAt(i)) {
                count++;
            } else {
                newStr.append(count);
                newStr.append(temp);
                count = 0;
            }
            temp = str.charAt(i);
            if(i == (str.length() - 1)){
                newStr.append(str.charAt(i));
            }
        }
        String x = String.valueOf(newStr);
        x = x.replace("0", "");
        System.out.print(x);
    }
}
```

But the output is:

```
2AB2SD
```

This result is not exactly what I want.

Please help me transform `"AABSSSD"` into `"2AB3SD"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `else` part you should set counter to `1` instead of `0` as new character is having it's first occurrence,

```
else {
    newStr.append(count);
    newStr.append(temp);
    count = 1;//Just change this
}
```

and replace `1` instead of `0` from the `String` `x = x.replace("1", "");` because `0A` does not look valid as `A` occurred once in the `String` so it should be `1A` instead of `0A`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `else` part is erroneous.
Please edit it as:

```
newStr.append(count);
newStr.append(temp);
count = 1;
```

instead of:

```
newStr.append(count);
newStr.append(temp);
count = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

What about a little bit of Java 8? :-)

```
String str = "AABSSSD";
String x = Arrays.stream(str.split(""))
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity())).values().stream()
    .map(l -> (l.size() > 1 ? l.size() : "") + l.get(0))
    .collect(Collectors.joining());
System.out.println(x);
```